# Getting error while adding record into mongodb using mongoose and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting the following error while adding some record into mongodb.

> Error:
>
> User.create is not a function /--/ "TypeError: User.create is not a
> function\n    at module.exports.createUsers

Here I am sending some data from postman and my aim is add them into mongodb database. I am explaining my mongo connect file first.

**mongo.js**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose;
const config = require('../config/settings');
const { MONGO_DB } = require('../config/settings');

const mongooseInstance = new mongoose();
const url = `mongodb://${config.MONGO_USER}:${config.MONGO_PWD}@${config.MONGO_URL}/${MONGO_DB}`;
const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    connectTimeoutMS: 5000000,
    poolSize: 10000,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
};

/*
 1- Connect to mongo server
*/

mongooseInstance.connect(url, options, (err) => {
    if(!err) {
        console.log('Mongodb connection successed');
    } else {
        console.log('Error in DB connection:' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, true));
    }
})

module.exports = mongooseInstance;
```

The above file used to make connection to my mongodb. I am explaining my code below.

**user.js**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const User = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    mobile: { type: String},
    email: { type: String},
    city: { type: String}
}, {
    timestamps: {
        CreatedAt: 'CreatedAt',
        UpdatedAt: 'UpdatedAt'
    },
    collection : 'user'
});

module.exports = User;
```

The above file is my model file. my controller file is given below.

**user-controller.js**:

```
const User = require('../models/user');

/*
 1- Add user.
*/

module.exports.createUsers = function (req, res,next) {

  const data = req.body;
  user = User.create(data);

  if(!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, res: []}).end('');
  } else {
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, res: user}).end('');
  }
}
```

Here I am trying to create the record but getting the above issue. I need to add record to user collection. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your modals' export statement as

```
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model first of your schema.
Simply create it with the following command and export the variable:

```
const userModel = mongoose.model('user', User);

module.exports = userModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

In *user.js* change...

`module.exports = User;`

to...

`module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User)`

Answer (score 0):

In your `user.js` file, you need to update `module.exports = User` with `module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User)`. Because in Mongoose, models are defined by passing a `Schema` instance to `mongoose.model`.

Answer (score 0):

here you need to make two changes

### first change

change in user.js where

```
module.exports = User;
```

to

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

### second change

in user-controller.js where

```
const data = req.body;
  user = User.create(data);

  if(!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, res: []}).end('');
  } else {
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, res: user}).end('');
  }
```

to

```
    // creating user of mongooes 
    User.create({
    // chooser the parameter according you writting this is just for the sample purpose
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }).then( (user) => {
        res.json(user)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.json(error);
    });
```